# When data blocks are fetched while scheduling map task?

Tags: hadoop, bigdata

In default hadoop scheduler a queue is maintained for different jobs for scheduling purpose and when a job reaches head of line it is scheduled. Since, data block corresponding to map task is required. So, When is this data block fetched ? 
1) When node gets a free slot and job is at the head of line.
or 2) When job enters into queue.

Comment: What you mean by "fetch"? Written to splits file? Stream created for reading?

Comment: I meant latter one